# How to create a flow or apex to check if an agent is available that I can call as an action in Einstein Chat Bot

Tags: einstein-chatbot

I'm a new junior developer/admin (six months) and I am lost. I am building Einstein bot for the first time.

The scenario is if there are no agents online then customers will be able to create a case. I have that set-up for three dialogue using the standard No Agent dialogue in Einstein bot but I have a fourth dialogue where if there are no agents available then customers can either create a case or request for a callback. (It will create a case that has the highest level priority in the queue so  Agents will be able to call that customer)

I can't reference the default **No Agent dialogue box** which checks if there are agents online then redirects them to create a case because I need to attach another option for a callback.

So I need to set-up a new dialogue that will act as a No Agent Dialogue for the callback which means I need to be able to check if agents are online or not. Which means I need to create either a Flow or Apex that I can call to check if there agents available and I am stumped.
I've been trying to research this for hours but I haven't seen any documentation for this.

Does anyone have any suggestions or resources I can check out so I can solve this one? I could really use some advice.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to implement the Apex solution of this article https://org62.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#000000000062/a/0M000000B9UO/Ye2gB_LiNeo.BaVh16aU0tzEAyAkFNUNzsjPLSm21J4

But I am getting an error on the Class 'CookbookBot_CheckAgentAvailability'

The error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getButtonAvailabilityForTransfer(String, String) from the type CookbookBot_REST_Utils "

Could someone please help me out?
I wonder if there any any solution in flow as well

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! This is a Questions & Answers site, not a threaded forum. Please see the various pertinent/relevant notes in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), & be aware that your "answer" will likely be deleted. You could ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) & in it you can link to this question or its other answer for reference (just click "Share" at bottom left of the post to get a URL). *If you do post a question, include the pertinent code directly in it.*

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/183889)

Answer (score 0):

It may be late, but this link its helpfull
https://org62.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#000000000062/a/0M000000B9UO/Ye2gB_LiNeo.BaVh16aU0tzEAyAkFNUNzsjPLSm21J4

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged and may be deleted. *(See: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers))* Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/379956/edit) your answer to add more information. *(From [How do I write a good answer?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): "...please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link....")*